# Call python script from AIR application?

Tags: python, flex3, air

How can we invoke a python script using AIR 1.5?

Comment: AIR 2.0 adds Native API calls which can be used for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly invoke system commands or run an executable (the python interpreter) from within an AIR application. If it's possible to share what exactly you want to do, maybe we can suggest alternatives.

If it's really really (that's two reallys) important to run an executable from AIR lookup the CommandProxy demo.

Answer (score 0):

For example through AMF: http://pyamf.org/

Answer (score 0):

Air 2.0 has a native process API.

Answer (score -1):

Hypothetically, Adobe Alchemy technology may allow you to port Python interpreter to Flash.

Though I seriously doubt that's the approach you want to use. Depending on task there should be easier solutions.